# Initialize part of Redux store on demand

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm migrating my Reflux based application to the Redux and came across one issue. I have many stores in the application (which is a good or bad thing about Reflux) and some of them get initialized only when a certain page trying to use the store. Basically, the store initialization happens then a component connected to the store is about to mount. When initialising the store I actually loading the data asynchronously.

To illustrate the current behavior: 
Suppose I have 5 pages and 5 stores, where each page using one store. The data for initial store state loaded only when the user navigates to the respective page. So, on initial application load, I only load data for store1 and only when user navigating to the page2 I'll load data for store2.

Now, I replacing my Reflux stores with a single Redux store which is consist of 5 parts and I'm planning to implement reducers for each of the parts. Every page if going to be associated with a reducer (page1 -> reducer1, page2->reducer2 etc.).  From my understanding of how Redux is supposed to work, each parts of the store will be initialized by a respective reducer and it all will happen at the store initialization time. In the real  application, I have, 50  stores, and I assume it will results in 50 API calls immediately at the application initialization which is not good at all.  Not all of that data is required for the initial page.

**Therefore my question**: Is there any way to load the initial store state on demand in Redux? Or how could it be approached?

I understand, that I can fire an action to load data into the store before navigating to the page, but in reality,  pages connected to several store parts and it is not easy to figure out what actions I need to call (although it is possible).

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393176/redux-loading-initial-state-asynchronously) but my question more about how to not load everything on initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

When you create your reducer, it is an good idea to give the `state` argument an default value so that when it is never undefined.

When you first initialize your store, you have the opportunity to pass down an `initialState` object. So you can do something like this:

```
let initialState;
if (yourDemand) { // load the intialState on 'yourDemand'
  initialState = {
    page1: intial state for page1Reducer
    page2: intial state for page2Reducer
    page3: intial state for page3Reducer
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState
);
```

Comment: If I need to do ajax call to get initial state, this will produce 3 calls at the same time, will it?

Comment: @MikhailChibel if they are retrieved asynchronously, I would make them an action, and dispatch the action when initialize, it would make the code much more clean